# app inventor selecting random item from a list one time only

Tags: android, list, random, app-inventor

Hi I am creating this app for my internship. It's a palm reading app which was requested for whatever reason to be built using the MIT App Inventor 2.

Everything works great except on my last page which I need it to take **ONE Random 'fortune' from my fortunesList and display only that 'fortune'**.

I think I have it set correctly to do that, but it keeps blinking / keeps reloading??

thanks in advance...

Here are the blocks I am currently working with:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> set **Label1.text** to **pick a random item** get global **list**

see also the [documentation](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/lists.html#pickrandomitem)

**pick a random item**

[image]

Picks an item at random from the list.

**EDIT: see screenshot how to do it in your example** to pick a random item on each run of the app, then display the picked item in another screen

**Screen1**
[image]
**Screen fortunes**

[image]

see also [how to work with multiple screens](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php)

Comment: I have tried to use the random block [http://www.punxsen.com/blocksRandom.html but then my app gives me an error and kindof goes crazy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did change the textbox to a label. However, when I tried your example above it _still_ keeps randomly picking from my 60 'fortunes' and I need it to: **grab one fortune one time** - no more. That's the problem I have spent 3 days on with no solution.

Comment: Yes, each time you start the app, another random item will be picked. Do you want to pick a random item only on first run of the app instead?

Comment: Yes please! Only One item for each time the app is run.

Comment: in this case move your blocks to get a random item from the list into Screen1 and pass the fortune to display in the **open another screen with value** block

Comment: Sorry, I am new to using this block based program style. I'm studying Java / Android, first using Eclipse and then after many issues I moved into using Android Studio. Anyway, I'm little confused... Could you please give a little more detail to what you are suggesting? Thanks :)

Comment: My app has a Screen1 which is my timed Splash with logo, that moves into another page, which based on what the user picks, the app either closes or their camera opens, takes a pic, sends pic to another page via TinyDB and then some animation happens, and finally it is set to open the last page, which is my fortunes page. So everything else in my app runs nicely **except** that I am having trouble getting it to display **just ONE item ONLY** from my list.

Comment: Thank you and I got it to work so it only pulls one random fortune. But the last page keeps blinking or reloading? Any ideas as to why and how to fix that?

Comment: I figured out how to stop the page from reloading... I just unchecked TimerAlwaysFires and then set it up to start/true and stop/false. But thank you again for your help!!